# Blocking access to a website based on domain name

Tags: security, website

I know there are ways to prevent access to a website based on IP addresses...

Now consider a company having it's own network, domain and mail service. I need to give access to a website only when it is accessed through this network. The catch is i have to do this based on the network's domain name... and not the IP address...

Is there a way to do this...?

Comment: Is the web site hosted in a server you manage ? Is so which one ?

Comment: yes.. the one with the limited access will be in my server....

Comment: How many domains do you have in your network ? What is the Web server type (IIS/Apache) ?

Answer (score 1):

If its Apache take a look at [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html) If its IIS just go to the site properties, directory security tab and IP address and domain restrictions or check [here](http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/IIS/blockip/)